# How to get Android Camera Preview ratio 1:1

Tags: android, android-layout, camera

I am trying to implement the a Android camera preview and want to have it display in 1:1 ratio (just like the Instagram camera).

I know how to deal with the preview frame size to be 1:1, but the camera output shows on the preview is squeezed. It looks like the live preview is still in 4:3 ratio but is squeezed to 1:1 frame. Is there a way to have the live preview also in 1:1 ratio?

I am not pasting any code here because I have tried many approach but all failed, nothing I can post...

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have noticed, camera preview frames are 4:3. Often, you can also **setPreviewSize()** to have aspect ratio ~9:4 (e.g. 800x480). I have not encountered an Android device that will have a square among **getSupportedPreviewSizes()**.

Your options to display a square preview are as follows: overlay the preview SurfaceView with non-transparent margins ontwo sides (effectively cropping the look). Or you could crop the image while displaying the **TextureSurface** through OpenGL. Or you could **setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()**, crop the yuv frame to your desired size, and display it (prefferably, through OpenGL).

Comment: Hi Alex: I am  like to capture square video with surface camera. As you told that "Or you could crop the image while displaying the TextureSurface through OpenGL.". Can you please give me some idea about that?

Comment: See e.g. https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/131670-cropping-2d-texture

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void setCameraPreview_Frame()
{
    RelativeLayout rel_Camera_Preview = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel_Camera_Preview);
    int width = rel_Camera_Preview.getWidth();
    int height = rel_Camera_Preview.getHeight();

    if(width<height)
        height = width;
    else
        width = height;

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
    layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    camera_preview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

camera_preview is your FrameLayout that contains Camera Preview.

### EDIT

And yes call this method like that

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus)
    {
        setCameraPreview_Frame();
    }
}
```

Comment: So `rel_Camera_Preview` is the parent container for `camera_preview`? I can't seem to get this to work. I just get a null pointer at `int width = rel_Camera_Preview.getWidth();`

Answer (score 0):

i know its an old question but here how i did it.

in your custom `SurfaceView` class add this

```
    @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()); //Snap to width
}
```

this will square the preview but not the image taken. here comes the trick

on capture `button` you'll have to `autoFocus` the `preview` first  and then immediately `stopPreivew`  in this case you'll stop '`freeze`' the `preview` and you can have the `surfaceView` inside of `FrameLayout` which its `height` set to `wrap_content` then you can save the cache view of that framelayout as `bitmap` and then save that `bitmap`.

Comment: This doesn't change the ratio of the preview that is being drawn the surface so it will still be squished, correct?

Comment: Yes correct, another solution is to draw over the camera perview something that make it looks like 1:1 but when the user capture the image you will here have to do some stuff to make sure the image is square